# app connects to mongo locally, but it seems that session creation fails when deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, express-session, mongodb-atlas

So, this is my first app deployment ever and I have the following problem.

I can use mongo (via atlas) when hosting locally no problem. Users are created on sign up and they have a session. When the code is deployed to heroku (via github connection) :

- **when the user goes to login** The login process times out. The console error/heroku logs below are displayed
- **when the user goes to sign up** The signup process times out, but the user is created in the db.

So, how can I get the sessions to be written to mongo db when its delopyed to heroku? My instinct is that I have the environment config  incorrect, but I have no idea where to go from there...

**console error :**

login:1 `POST https://my-berlin-map.herokuapp.com/login 503 (Service Unavailable)`

**heroku details**

`2020-11-25T17:07:49.775428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=POST path="/login" host=my-berlin-map.herokuapp.com request_id=f8671320-de7a-42c1-890d-4bdadca078a8 fwd="46.94.150.220" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55124ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https 2020-11-25T17:07:49.775925+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mPOST /login [36m302[0m 119.004 ms - 46[0m`

**In the .env file we've specified the following (and added them as vars to heroku)**

PORT=3000

ENV=development

MAPBOXSECRET= *key*

SESSION_SECRET=hunter2

MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://*username*:*password*@cluster0.lmmct.mongodb.net/*dbUser*?retryWrites=true&w=majority

**code details**

```
    require('dotenv').config();

const bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express      = require('express');
const favicon      = require('serve-favicon');
const hbs          = require('hbs');
const mongoose     = require('mongoose');
const logger       = require('morgan');
const path         = require('path');
    
    
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(x => {
    console.log(`Connected to Mongo! Database name: "${x.connections[0].name}"`)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err)
  });

    const app_name = require('./package.json').name;
    const debug = require('debug')(`${app_name}:${path.basename(__filename).split('.')[0]}`);

    const app = express();

    // Middleware Setup
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // session configuration
    const session = require('express-session');
    const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

    app.use(
      session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: true,
        store: new MongoStore({
          mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
          ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        })
      })
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, so beyond some needed clean up of promises, the core issue was that when I entered the variable for MONGO_URI in heroku, I added an extra space at the end.

that was it.